# Internet Accounts keeps asking me to log into Facebook, now wont sync calendars

Tags: mac, calendar, facebook

Only a few days ago i noticed my mac calendar wast syncing up with my facebook one but didn't think anything of it. 
Then next thing i know a notification pops up with 'cant connect to the account Facebook' and that i need to put in my password. I have done this now 20 times and it still just sends the same notification after putting in the 100% correct password. Unsure why it keeps looping around, not showing any signs of the details being incorrect. 
Please send help i really rely on the facebook calendar to be synced up with my mac calendar app.